# Which of these two approaches is faster in Redis? (HGETALL vs HMGET related)

Tags: optimization, redis

I have a frequently accessed web page in which I have the IDs of around 60-80 tags and want to get information about those items from Redis.

A tag has a name, a 'has_children' flag, and two or three other properties that need to be accessed.

There are two approaches that come to mind:

1. Store a hash for each tag.

   ```
   tag:123 --> {name: 'Football', has_children: True, ...}
   tag:345 --> {name: 'Cricket', has_children: False, ...}
   ```

   Then I would iterate over  those ~80 tag IDs and do a HGETALL call for each one. Pipelining would be used to not waste roundtrip time.
2. Another approach is to have a hash for each of the properties of a tag.

   ```
   tag_name --> {'tag:123': 'Football', 'tag:345': 'Cricket', ...}
   tag_has_children --> {'tag:123': True, 'tag:345': False, ...}
   ```

   In this approach, I would have make as many HMGET calls as there are properties I need. eg.

   ```
   HMGET tag_name tag:123 tag:345 ...
   HMGET tag_has_children tag:123 tag:345 ...
   ```

The number of calls is reduced from ~80 to 3 or 4.

Does the latter approach give any speed boost? Or does it make no difference because of how Redis works or something? Or is there a better way to do what I want?

Comment: The best way to answer this type of questions is to benchmark the different approaches. That said, I don't believe you'll find significant differences in performance between the two and the 1st approach makes more sense (since everything is neatly aggregated).

Comment: @ItamarHaber: I agree that the first approach is more organized. So the reduction in the number of calls in the second approach has no huge effect?

Comment: Benchmark it to be sure, but given the numbers involved and using pipelining I'm guessing any difference will be negligible.